# About some tikz styles

Tags: nodes, tikz-styles, tikz-node

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=0in,top=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\newcommand{\tikzmarkC}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline={-3pt}] \node[] (#1) {
};}

\tikzset{cloud/.pic={
\node[cloud, cloud puffs=10.8,cloud puff arc=110, aspect=2, draw, text width=3cm
    ] () at (0,0) {\tikzpictext};
}}
\begin{document}

$$\tikzmarkC{a}x = \tikzmarkC{b}y$$


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\pic (c1) at (5,3) [pic text=$x$ is ....]{cloud};
\pic (c2) at (15,3) [pic text=$y$ is ...]{cloud};
\draw[-latex'] (c1) to[bend left] (a);
\draw[-latex'] (c2) to[bend right]  (b);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which appear like

[image]

and I want to make something like this instead of the cloud, Any help, please?

[image]

Comment: Google tells me that TikZ has `rectangle callout` which I believe is what you want. http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/energy-levels/

Comment: @hpekristiansen thank you, sir, I saw that example but they are using coordinates and I don't know how to integrate that in my example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

**edit:**
added is in-line equation inside `callout` shape.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shapes.callouts,
                tikzmark}

\tikzset{CO/.style={% Call Out
    shape=rectangle callout,
    callout absolute pointer={#1},
    callout pointer width=1.2 mm,
    callout pointer shorten=-1mm,
    draw, semithick,
    align=left}
        }
\begin{document}

\[
\tikzmark{A}x = \tikzmark{B}y
\]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,
node distance=8mm and 4mm
                    ]
\coordinate[above=2ex of pic cs:A]  (a);
\coordinate[above right=2ex and 1ex of pic cs:B]  (b);
%
\node[CO=(a),above  left=of a] {$y=x^2+x+1$\\ BBBBBBBB};
\node[CO=(b),above right=of a] {AAAAAA\\ BBBBBBBB};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you like to have formula in call out shape? for example: `$y=x^2 + x  +1$` instead of for example `AAAAAA` doesn't work?

Comment: in my test it works. see edited answer. sorry, but i don't know your commands, so can't say anything about them.